# Concat and resorting dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, concatenation

I have 2 dataframes that were originally 1 dataframe, but split so I can handle data from each appropriately. I am now merging them back together and resorting them.

The original dataframe was sorted by the 'Time' column and then reset the index. The data was then split so that after I change the data I would be able to merge back in order due to the index.

So in the first 2 pictures is the concat dataframe into 1 dataframe. The 2nd picture with the index starting at 2 shows that was the one concat into the other dataframe. This layout is all currently correct with all the correct spacing.

[image: Data Before Resort (1)]

[image: Data Before Resort (2)]

Now when I apply the sort on the index, everything gets shifted to where it needs to be, but some of the data rows flip which then messes up the spacing.If you look at index 2, Toledo is now above UAB whereas before the sort, UAB was above Toledo. I am not sure why this is happening. I will provide my code below.

[image: After Sorting on Index]

```
# df_AT would be the 1st dataframe with the H/A in the column 'H/A'
# whereas df_VS has just N in the 'H/A' column

df_AT_VS = [df_AT, df_VS]
fin_df_Sched = pd.concat(df_AT_VS)
fin_df_Sched = fin_df_Sched.sort_index(axis=0)
```

Comment: Hiya - welcome to stackoverflow - take some time to read [mcve] and [ask] please provide your examples as text that others can copy into their editors to test with.

Comment: The data I am using is getting web scraped. I have been unable to recreate the issue on a smaller scale. That is why I just provided the pictures just to show that everything is in order until after the sort_index.

Answer (score 1):

As you have duplicated indices you likely want to use a [stable sorting](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Stable_sorts). The default method of [`sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) (quicksort) is not stable.

```
fin_df_Sched.sort_index(axis=0, kind='stable')
```